# Displaying output from a csv file with tkinter

Tags: tkinter

i am trying to display data from a csv file with tkinter, but the columns of data dont stay in line with each other, and the output isnt evenly tabbed, Is there another way that would show the output correctly.iI have tried the following:

```
f = open('name.csv')
output=''
for line in f:
    output += line.replace(',','\t')
f.close()

Results = Label(root, text = output)
Results.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.75, anchor=CENTER)
```

Comment: There are several ways to show the data correctly. You seem to be trying to cram everything into a single Label widget -- is that a requirement? Have you considered using a separate Label widget for each table cell? Have you tried using the text widget with a fixed width font? Does your data contain any cells with embedded newlines or uncharacteristically long lines?

Comment: hi, i stripped the file with                                                                           new_str = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.\-\:\%]', ' ', string, so it got rid of unwanted characters, it needs to be viewed as a table on a single widget, but its not lining up

Comment: if you get rid of all the newlines, how will you know when one record stops and the next one begins? Why must it be a single widget? Is it so that people can copy and paste the data?

Comment: that's allowing newlines. It got rid of commas, etc.  Its a single widget because i have a tkinter box with a choice to view different csv files, when you click on a certain radio button, the data from the matching  csv file appears, in a table like manner in the gui, but its not lining up evenly

Comment: Does the user need to be able to copy/paste the data, or is this strictly for viewing?

Comment: it is strictly for viewing